# I need erb to loop and render out the children of several objects and the children of the children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Lets say I have a collection of objects, and each one may or may not have children, and that child collection may or may not have children for an unknown number of generations.

How do I get erb to render all the way to the last child of each tree?

Humans

```
[
{name: bill, id: 1, human_id: nil},
{name: bob, id: 2, human_id: 1},
{name: john, id: 3, human_id: 2},
{name: marie, id: 4, human_id: 2},
{name: jake, id: 6, human_id: 5},
{name: anne, id: 5, human_id: nil},
]
```

As you can see there are two records that begin the tree (1 and 5), because they do not belong to anyone.

I need to render

```
bill
    bob
        john
        marie
anne
    jake
```

without knowing how many relationship layers there are

Comment: Submit some sample data with desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your `.erb` file

```
   <% @collection.each do |f| %>
     <% f.each do |x| %>
       <%= x.name %>
       <%= x.id %>
       <%= x.human_id %>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

You could put some `if statements` to check if a value is present

```
   <% @collection.each do |f| %>
     <% f.each do |x| %>
       <% if x.name.present? %>
        <%= x.name %>
       <% end %>
       <%= x.id %>
       <%= x.human_id %>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: the problem is I dont know how many children of children there are. The number of if statements could change.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with [this approach](https://github.com/nativestranger/cerializable#custom-serialization-options). It's the same problem (self-referential model with a need to render from the top down.)

Just create a method that represents an individual record as a hash. (In the model or in its serializer, like in the example.) Provide an option to pass in an array of the "children" hashes.

Then create a service to load all of the records & iterate through them, adding their hashes to your result (building their children arrays each time) until you've built the whole structure. You can store the records in a hash with their ids as keys and delete them as they're added to your result.

If you used cerializable, your serializer would be something like this:

```
module HumanSerializer

  def run(human, options)
    { id: human.id,
      name: human.name,
      parent_id: human.parent_id,
      children: options[:children] || human.children.map(&:cerializable_hash)
  end

end
```

And then you could use a service like this to build the tree:

```
class AncestryTree
  def self.call(humans)
    self.new(humans).tree
  end

  def initialize(humans)
    @humans_hash = {}
    humans.each { |human| @humans_hash[human.id] = human }

    @children_resolver = proc do |parent|
      children_array = []

      @humans_hash.each_pair do |id, human|
        if human.parent_id && human.parent_id == parent.id
          @humans_hash.delete(id)
          children_array << human.cerializable_hash(children: @children_resolver.call(human))
        end
      end

      children_array
    end
  end

  def tree
    @result = []        

    @humans_hash.each_pair do |id, human|
      if human.parent_id.nil?
        @humans_hash.delete(id)
        @result << human.cerializable_hash(children: @children_resolver.call(human))
      end
    end

    @result
  end
end
```

(Just wrote this based on the README example, didn't test, but you get the idea.)

I'd use React components make it easier to render the nested structure in the view.